# Using DataFrame.Multiply on 2 Data Frames with 1 Having multi-level headers

Tags: python, dataframe, multiplication

I am loading 2x csv files into 2 separate dataframes and then trying to multiple the column of one dataframe against all the columns of another dataframe to create a third dataframe.  Both csvs and dataframes have the same number of rows and same date data in column 1.  The problem I am having is that I cannot seem to get this to work as the first dataframe only has 1 header (row 1) and the second dataframe has 3 headers (rows 1-3). To get around this I inserted two rows in the underlying csv data for the first data frame (i.e. rows 2 and 3 are empty) so that both csv and dataframes would have the same rows.  The csv loads on that basis. I then though I could reindex the first dataframe based on the second dataframe.

The code fails on df_revenue = line with the following error:

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,2) (3,) (1,2)

```
import pandas as pd
# load Production csv file specifying the header rows and index columns
df_production = pd.read_csv('ProductionL.csv', header=[0, 1, 2], index_col=0)
df_production.index = pd.to_datetime(df_production.index)
print(df_production.head(10))
#replace blanks with zeros in production data frame and replace any remaining zeros with NaN
df_production.fillna(0, inplace = True)
df_production.replace(0, np.nan, inplace = True)
print(df_production.head(10))
# Pull in commodity price data
df_commodity = pd.read_csv('Commodity_Prices.csv', header=[0,1,2],index_col=0)
df_commodity.index = pd.to_datetime(df_commodity.index)
print(df_commodity.head(10))
# extract the commodity price column as a DataFrame
commodity_col  = df_commodity['ACTUAL_POOL_PRICE']
print(commodity_col.head(10))
#multiply the commodity column with all the production columns
df_revenue = df_production.multiply(commodity_col.reindex(df_production.index, method='ffill'))
print(df_revenue.head(10))
```

Comment: can you please provide sample data (input dataframes) and desired output? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for producing minimal reproducible example. It will help us understand what you need - thanks!